# Convert a simple Object to a Complex array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been trying to map the following object to the following array, I am quite new to map/sort and reduce. Is it even possible to do acquire the wanted result?

**From:**

```
{
  boxer: Array []
  brabancon: Array []
  briard: Array []
  bulldog: Array [ "boston", "french" ]
}
```

**To:**

```
[
  {dogBreed: 'boxer'},
  {dogBree: 'brabancon'},
  {dogBree: 'briard'},
  {dogBree: 'bulldog (boston)'},
  {dogBree: 'bulldog (french)'}
]
```

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried to the questions as a [mcve]?

Comment: Ok, you don't have any experience with those methods.  Try to do something, even it doesn't work. Then come back in order to get help from SO's community.

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Then describe your strategy thus far, code setup + conditions, and the errors/issues. Also state 'obvious' context that you already know, so that people understand what you have tried. See also [1](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map` is not a good approach since in some cases you need to have more then one element per key. You could use `reduce` instead. Here is an example.

```js
var org = {
  boxer: [],
  brabancon: [],
  briard: [],
  bulldog: [ "boston", "french" ]
}

var arr = Object.keys(org).reduce((acc, key) => {
  if(org[key].length){
    org[key].forEach(v => acc.push({dogBreed: `${key} (${v})`}));
  }else{
    acc.push({dogBreed: key});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code sample (Old way):

```js
var res = []

var obj = {
  boxer: [],
  brabancon: [],
  briard: [],
  bulldog: [ "boston", "french" ]
}

for (var key in obj) {
   if (!obj[key].length) {
       res.push({
          dogBreed: key
       })
   } else {
       for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
           res.push({
              dogBreed: key + ' (' + obj[key][i] + ')'
           })
       }
   }
}
console.log(res)
```

Or Using +ES2015 with reduce or map

```js
const obj = {
  boxer: [],
  brabancon: [],
  briard: [],
  bulldog: [ "boston", "french" ]
}

result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((arr, key) => {
   if (obj[key].length) {
    obj[key].forEach((item) => {arr.push({dogBreed: `${key} (${item})`})})
   } else {
    arr.push({dogBreed: key})
   }
   return arr;
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

For more information, this [video](https://youtu.be/Wl98eZpkp-c) helped me to understand reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const input = {
  boxer: [],
  brabancon: [],
  briard: [],
  bulldog: ['boston', 'french'],
};

console.log([].concat(...Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) =>
  (value.length > 0 ? value : ['']).map(x => ({ dogBreed: key + (x ? ` (${x})` : '') }))
)));
```

The `[].concat(...)` part is used to flatten the array, i.e. convert an array of arrays of objects into an array of objects.

For more explanation, see the docs: [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys to get keys of the object into array. then loop through array and push every single object into the new array.

```
var obj = {
   boxer: [],
   brabancon: [],
   briard:  [],
   bulldog: [ "boston", "french" ]
}

var arr = Object.keys(obj);
var newArr =[];

arr.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
  newArr.push({'breed':element})
});
```

Please see the link :
https://jsfiddle.net/vrfj6o05/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
let testing = {
  boxer: [],
  brabancon: [],
  briard: [],
  bulldog: [ "boston", "french" ]
}

function convertToObjectArray(testing, objKey) {
  let array = [];
  Object.keys(testing).forEach(function(el) {
    if(testing[el] && testing[el].length > 0) {
      testing[el].forEach(function(e) {
        let obj = {};
        obj[objKey] = el + ' (' + e + ')';
        array.push(obj);
      });
    }
    else {
      let obj = {};
      obj[objKey] = el;
      array.push(obj);
    }
  });
  return array;
}

let finalArray = convertToObjectArray(testing, 'dogBreed');
console.log(finalArray);
```